# Fix image dimensions / slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to display some images in a view as a slideshow. Each image has different dimensions. These different dimensions making the slideshow weird. Is there any possibility to change the image dimensions to one fixed dimension. I hope I explained my problem clearly if not please excuse me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAAAAAAAAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZW..." alt="image1">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAAAAAAAAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm..." alt="image2">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAAAAAAAAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWN..." alt="image3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have described nicely your problem. Adding also your code it would make it easier for the readers of your post to think also in terms of your code. Thanks

Comment: cant you just set the width? however if they have different aspect ratio then you are screwed

Comment: ASP.NET MVC and C# are irrelevant here, none of them can help you with an HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: I thought we could change the image dimension in MVC controller before we pass it to the view. Thank you for your edit @CamiloTerevinto.

Comment: That's an entirely different question. You have to know whether you want a front-end library to solve your problem (which there are dozens) or you want to actually change the images through code

Comment: Sorry @CamiloTerevinto for not asking my problem clearly. If it is possible to fix my problem by using front end libraries that would be great.

Comment: I edited and added my HTML code @Christos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line of code to your stylesheet file

```
.slideshow img { height: 380px;width: 100%}
```

then add "slideshow" class to the div that contains the slideshow images and items.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, unless you want to stretch the images (change the aspect ratio), which in my opinion is a bad idea.

If you look at [this ad on Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/nz/listing/598914534/rosewood-bridesmaid-dress-infinity-dress?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=&ref=sc_gallery-1-3&plkey=79e09cb138900a0ebe9edd1c13790687d6a08e0c%3A598914534&ep_click=1&pro=1&col=1) they are using a fixed width and maintain the aspect ratio of the image, so height is variable... which means if the image is too short there will be blank space on the top and bottom of the image...